# jQuery selector with ids and comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [MyTableGrid](http://pabloaravena.info/mytablegrid/) to show an Excel like control in my webpage.

The cells are referenced with ids like "mtgIC1_0,2" for table 1, column 0, row 2.

Unfortunately, when I try to use the jQuery selector with this id `$("#mtgIC1_0,2")`, it never works.

I figured it is because of the "," since it works for any other ids in the page without coma.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

However if you escape the comma it should still work

e.g

```
$('#mtgIC1_0\\,2')
```

Comment: Note that the first part of this answer is specific to is for HTML4 and below, so this won't be valid later on :)

Comment: Blarg, I was escaping with a single \ =(

Comment: @redsquare - That's a legit concern...but pages that are HTML5 are a current reality, not something 5 years from now, so it's something to keep in mind for current developers finding this as well.

Comment: @NickCraver not really a concern of mine, I was 'trying' to be sarcastic:)

Answer (score 3):

From here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

"`If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an an input with name="names[]", you can use the selector $("input[name=names\\[\\]]").`"

Comment: Although correct to escape special characters... As @redsquare notes - ID identifiers can not legally contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know offhand if this is the reason, but according to [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), ID names should not contain commas. The relevant sentence is:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: thanks, but "should not happen" and "stuck to deal with it" are two different worlds =)

Answer (score 1):

If you have known coordinates of the table, you can target the cell like this:

```
$('#myTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', '#F00');
```