# Unable to remove one element from html in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to remove element by id. Its not removed.

```
var html = '<div id="cke_column_description[-2]" class="cke_1 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_column_description[-2] cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="cs" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_column_description[-2]_arialbl" style="width: 178px;">
    <span id="cke_column_description[-2]_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">CMS WYSIWYG editor.</span>
    <div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation">
        <span id="cke_1_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" role="presentation" style="height: auto; user-select: none;">
            <span id="cke_11" class="cke_voice_label">Panely nástrojů editoru</span>
            <span id="cke_1_toolbox" class="cke_toolbox" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_11" onmousedown="return false;">
                <span class="cke_toolbox_main iterate_tbx_hidden" style=""></span>
                <a title="Zobrazit panel nástrojů" id="cke_1_toolbar_collapser" tabindex="-1" class="cke_toolbox_collapser cke_toolbox_collapser_min" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(2)">
                    <span class="cke_arrow">◀</span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 100px;">
            <span id="cke_15" class="cke_voice_label">Stiskněte ALT 0 pro nápovědu</span>
            <iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="CMS WYSIWYG editor." aria-describedby="cke_15" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
        <span id="cke_1_bottom" class="cke_bottom cke_reset_all" role="presentation" style="user-select: none;">
        <span id="cke_1_resizer" class="cke_resizer cke_resizer_vertical cke_resizer_ltr" title="Uchopit pro změnu velikosti" onmousedown="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(0, event)">◢</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>';

var htmlParsed = jQuery(html);
htmlParsed.remove("div#cke_column_description[-2]");
console.log(htmlParsed);
```

Am I dooing something wrong? Thank you for help.

Comment: because [] is an attribute selector Read the first paragraph https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Also the argument to `remove()` is the *filter*, it's not a selector. You need to `find()` the element to remove within the `htmlParsed` object, then call `remove()` on that with no arguments.

Comment: you need to use (``) backticks for multiline strings.

Comment: put html code in a JS variable, it's really bad, it has other solutions already described here !

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208887/2181514

Comment: Brackets must be slashed. Something like this: htmlParsed.remove("div#cke_column_description\\[-2\\]");